# Rationalizing Denominators with Radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you rationalize this fraction:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rationalize the Denominator by Default](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/rationalize-the-denominator-by-default)

Comment: thanks, but I'm trying to do it by hand... Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I must have clicked the wrong place or was redirected incorrectly. But thanks for the help. I was over-thinking it with the conjugate things.

Answer (score 1):

To rationalize the denominator given:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

1) Multiply both the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{n+1}$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\times\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

2) This leaves us with:
$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}}}$$

3) Simplifying we are left with:

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{{n+1}}$$

Because:

$$\sqrt{n+1}\times\sqrt{n+1} = n+1$$

Answer (score 0):

well... you should agree that $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}=1$, given $n\neq-1$; thus
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n+1}\,.$$
Is this what you wanted?

Comment: @Sujaan Kunalan: OK, you are right but this is clearly implicit in the question as already in the original text we are dividing by $\sqrt{n+1}$. This is why I do not find it necessary to specify this hypothesis in my answer!